# Updating a many to many table with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I have a table with animals

```
CREATE TABLE Animals
(
AnimalId int NOT NULL,
Color int NOT NULL,
Breed int NOT NULL,
Genre int NOT NULL,
);
```

And a table exactly the same but everything is optional (except the key)

```
CREATE TABLE Expenses
(
ExpenseId int NOT NULL,
Color int,
Breed int,
Genre int,
);
```

And finally a many to many table:

```
CREATE TABLE AnimalsExpenses
(
ExpenseId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Expenses(ExpenseId),
AnimalId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Animals(AnimalId),
);
```

The record (a, e) should be on the table AnimalsExpenses if

```
((SELECT Color FROM Animals WHERE AnimalId = a) = (SELECT Color FROM Expenses WHERE ExpenseId = e)
OR (NULL) = (SELECT Color FROM Expenses WHERE ExpenseId = e))
AND
((SELECT Breed FROM Animals WHERE AnimalId = a) = (SELECT Breed FROM Expenses WHERE ExpenseId = e)
OR (NULL) = (SELECT Breed FROM Expenses WHERE ExpenseId = e))
AND
((SELECT Genre FROM Animals WHERE AnimalId = a) = (SELECT Genre FROM Expenses WHERE ExpenseId = e)
OR (NULL) = (SELECT Genre FROM Expenses WHERE ExpenseId = e))
```

...how would it be a query that updates AnimalsExpenses ? that is: it removes the records that shouldn't be on the n-m table and it adds the ones that need to be there

Example:

```
------ Animals -------------------
 AnimalId  Color  Breed  Genre
----------------------------------
     1      1       1      1
     2      1       1      2
     3      1       2      2

----- Expenses -------------------
 ExpenseId  Color  Breed  Genre
----------------------------------
     1       NULL   NULL   NULL      (applies to every animal)
     2       NULL    2     NULL      (applies to animals of breed 2)
     3         1     2      2        (applies exactly to animal 3)

----- AnimalsExpenses -------------------------------------------
  AnimalId   ExpenseId   Is it ok?
-----------------------------------------------------------------
      1        1         yes, because "expense 1" applies to all
      2        1         yes, because "expense 1" applies to all
      3        1         yes, because "expense 1" applies to all

      1        2         no, breed doesnt match
      2        2         no, breed doesnt match
      3        2         yes, because "expense 2" matches breed with "animal 3"

      1        3         no, breed and genre doesnt match
      2        3         no, breed doesnt match
      3        3         yes, everything matches
```

Comment: Which SQL vendor are you using?  I might enforce this in the app layer rather than in the database.

Comment: SQL Server. I was doing this update with LINQ / Entity Framework but it was too slow

Comment: Could you include some sample data and show us what an allowed and a forbidden entry would look like?

Comment: I've given an example

Comment: So is your logic that either the `Animals` table has the same value for all columns, or the breeds match?  Otherwise discard the record?  Explain what "applies to all" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just truncate the table and then run

```
Insert into AnimalsExpenses
select a.AnimalId
  , e.ExpenseId
  from Animals a
  inner join Expenses e on a.Breed = ISNULL(e.Breed, a.Breed) 
          AND a.Color = ISNULL(e.Color, a.Color) 
          AND a.Genre = ISNULL(e.Genre, a.Genre)
```

Comment: Truncate means to remove all the rows? I will try... sounds like a good answer. How well will it perform with 1000 animals and 20 expenses (aprox)?

Comment: @sports Truncate means delete all rows, it's a command. Shouldn't be too bad. I updated the answer by the way, ORs need to be ANDs

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to rewrite the `WHERE` criteria this way:

```
ISNULL(Expenses.Color, Animals.Color) = Animals.Color
AND ISNULL(Expenses.Breed, Animals.Breed) = Animals.Breed
AND ISNULL(Expenses.Genre, Animals.Genre) = Animals.Genre
```

Take a look also to `COALESCE`.